# Regex pattern fails

Tags: c#, regex

```
string[] data=File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\data.txt");

string pattern = @"\d{1,2} " + @"\w{1,9} " + @"\d{4}";

foreach (string operand in data)
{               
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(operand,pattern));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

In output i am getting some dates like the above pattern but the `Regex.Match` is not extracting all of my dates what should i do ?

Comment: What's "not working" about it? - What sample values aren't being picked up?

Comment: its not extracting all dates from the file.

Comment: Are the failing dates all in "September" (which has 10 characters in its name, not 9, per your regular expression)

Comment: Or do they have varing amounts of whitespace?

Comment: try to extract dates and then use DateTime.Parse()

Comment: Which dates have the problem. Show some data from the file

Comment: no not just september it is also failing at august means it extracts 10 August 1947 but it fails at 14 August 1947

Comment: no white spaces are same they do not varry

Comment: i tried DateTime.Parse() but the results are worse than this method.

Comment: Show the *full line* from the text file that's failing, please.

Comment: File data  Born Mahomedali Jinnahbhai
25 December 1876
Karachi, British India
Died 11 September 1948
Karachi, Pakistan
Political party 
Indian National Congress (1906–20)
All-India Muslim League (1913–47)
Muslim League (1947–48)

Comment: And this line fails? I ran it through your code and I get `25 December 1876`

Comment: this line is failing from the start 25 December 1876

Comment: but why is is not giving me that date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated your problem and every thing was fine.

**Code:**

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\data.txt");

string pattern = @"\d{1,2} " + @"\w{1,9} " + @"\d{4}";

foreach (string operand in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(operand, pattern));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**File Data:**

```
Born    
Mahomedali Jinnahbhai 25 December 1876 Karachi, British India 
Died 11 September 1948 Karachi, Pakistan 
Political party 
Indian National Congress (1906–20) 
All-India Muslim League (1913–47) 
Muslim League (1947–48)
Pakistan came into being on 14 August 1947
not on 10 august 1947
```

**Output:**

[image]

I hope you will get something from the explanation.

Comment: thanks man i think the text file format is messing with my code.